# Update shopping cart with more variants

Tags: php, html, forms, shopping-cart

I am currently trying to create shopping cart and send it throught $_SESSION variable.

But when I try to update items via $_POST, it only updates the last product in cart.

Here is my form

```
<form method="post">
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) { 
$productDetail = Products::getProduct($product['id']);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $product['id']; ?>">
<input name="qty" size="5" maxlength="50" type="text" value="<?= $product['quantity']; ?>">
<input name="width" size="5" maxlength="50" type="text" value="<?= $product['width']; ?>">
<input name="length" size="5" maxlength="5" type="text" value="<?= $product['length']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Here how i update my cart

```
$item_id = $data['id'];
$quantity = $data['qty'];
$width = $data['width'];
$length = $data['length'];

$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['width'] = $width;
$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['length'] = $length;
```

It always updates only the last one in form.

Is there some or better solution to this problem?
I would very appriciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `[]` to input names to get arrays in `$_POST` values:

```
<form method="post">
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) { 
$productDetail = Products::getProduct($product['id']);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?= $product['id']; ?>">
<input name="qty[]" size="5" maxlength="50" type="text" value="<?= $product['quantity']; ?>">
<input name="width[]" size="5" maxlength="50" type="text" value="<?= $product['width']; ?>">
<input name="length[]" size="5" maxlength="5" type="text" value="<?= $product['length']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Then you can iterate over `$data['id']` array (I assume here that it is the same as `$_POST['id']`), taking advantage from the fact that those 4 arrays have the same corresponding key for given data set:

```
$item_ids = $data['id'];
$quantitys = $data['qty'];
$widths = $data['width'];
$lengths = $data['length'];

foreach($item_ids as $k=>$item_id){
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['quantity'] = $quantitys[$k];
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['width'] = $widths[$k];
    $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['length'] = $lengths[$k];
}
```